# Node.js installation troubles

Tags: node.js, iis-7.5

I followed the installation instructions provided by [Hanselman](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/InstallingAndRunningNodejsApplicationsWithinIISOnWindowsAreYouMad.aspx) but the only thing I can do calling the hello.js is actually downloading the js file...

I checked the module - it is registered in IIS. I am running on version IIS 7.5. What can be the problem?

Comment: Uh, just curious, but why would you want to run node on IIS? Node can stand on its own two feet, and is very easy to get a simple server up. Also, node is not even stable on Windows...

Comment: The link you provided is a pretty complex install. I hope you have a good use case for this and followed the instructions completely. You may get a better answer if you post a comment to Hanselman's blog post

Comment: @tjameson Well... I read the post and tried! What do you suggest me for trying in a Windows install? I don't need it 100% stable, I just want to try it :)

Comment: @Deep Kapadia 
it's a 5 step installation, it doesn't look so complex to me... I tried with this one, same problem
https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode

Comment: If you just want to experiment with Node, just download `Node.exe` from the Node site and run it on the command line with `C:\path\to\node.exe myscript.js`, no need to run it through IIS.

Comment: Thanks Brandon, I will try that one

Comment: If the file downloaded you probably misconfigured the web.config. He shows 3 different exemples, the first one is the "good" one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everybody for your advice. 
Few days ago Hanselman posted this one that make life easier if you want to start using [node.js with IIS on windows](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/WebMatrixAndNodejsTheEasiestWayToGetStartedWithNodeOnWindows.aspx)