# how to keep a node server app running on windows server

Tags: node.js

I'm working on a project and I have modified node.js' 'simple chat room' sample application for my need, it works fine.

I have to call the server app's url (the .js file) to start it before opening the client page in the browser, so far everything works fine. But if the node server app goes down for any reason (server restart, iis restart, etc), the client page returns an error .

My question is, how can I keep the node server app alive all the time even after it interrupted. How can I do that without having a monitor or a script which runs every x minutes.

I'm using IIS 7.5 and iisnode module.

Thanks

Comment: Why not just run node as a service with `nssm`?

Comment: nssm looks promising, I will give it a try.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Run your script file, as a service, with [nssm](http://nssm.cc/).

Comment: Interesting option. I'm upvoting as a general solution, but I recommend my answer below for Node so that no part of the app or it's environment becomes platform specific.

Comment: The question was platform specific, and by the way you still need to start nodemon, and supervisor if you restart your machine, while using nssm, it's automatically up and running on a restart, however for development, I use nodemon too :)

Answer (score 4):

Pretty sure you'll want [jesus](https://github.com/deoxxa/jesus)

#### Installation

```
$ npm install -g jesus
```

#### Usage

Start monitoring server

```
$ jesus daemon /path/to/server.log
```

To start a process

```
$ jesus start <id> node /path/to/my-app/index.js
```

To stop one

```
$ jesus stop <id>
```

To stop all

```
$ jesus stopall
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about running node in iis. However, you can take a look at the node packages `forever`, `pm2`, and `nodemon`, which will recover the instance in case of failure.

[Here's how to install node.js as a service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10547974/how-to-install-node-js-as-windows-service)

[Here's something on installing node in iis 7.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7410145/node-js-installation-troubles)

---

Just an update.

I've been using iisnode at work for the better part of a year. I would recommend it if you are deploying to Windows.

Comment: forever doesn't work in Windows as of now without some special considerations (which I'm yet to discover)

Comment: I have put a lot of time into iisnode and finally gave up. Also, I run on both platforms so it wouldn't be a solve-all. See my answer below for my present solution(s).

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/isaacs/node-supervisor and https://github.com/remy/nodemon have slightly different feature sets, but aren't Windows specific and still work on Windows unlike many of the other more popular, yet incomplete options such as forever and eternity (as of today anyway).