# Basic windows script to keep node running

Tags: windows, node.js, batch-file, dos

I am using the following very very basic script in a .bat file to keep a node.js server running on a windows machine.

```
: loop
npm start
goto loop
: end
```

However, if the server goes down, it does not restart automatically.

I do know that there are preferable ways of keeping the node up and running ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18391517/how-to-keep-a-node-server-app-running-on-windows-server)), but I really want to focus on other parts of the code at the moment and keep on integrating with other partners there. Thus, I am really looking for a very very simple bat file that can restart the server when it goes down (on Windows). What can possibly be wrong with the above one that I have?

Comment: it might go wrong if the server goes *down* not as you think it does. There are many ways of application crashing, one of which makes application hang, thus the script never gets to the stage `goto loop`. Why not use `nodemon` module?

Comment: Thank you. I am merely referring to crashing though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably (you will have to check it), npm is a batch file (`.bat` or `.cmd`).

When you invoke a batch file from another batch file, the execution is transfered to the called batch and does not return to the caller. In your case, your `goto loop` is never reached as `npm` will never return

You need to use `call npm start`, so the execution will continue in the caller when the called batch ends.

Comment: This looks like it solves the problem. I can see two node instances running on the task manager, and when I terminate one of them it restarts as expected. Thank you for your time and the educated guess. :)